# Можно ли делать возврат из блока using(){}?

Tags: c#, try-catch, return, using

Можно ли делать возврат из тела блока using? Будут ли освобождены неуправляемые ресурсы?

Comment: да. почитайте [спецификацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11776945/2110496